# How to SSH to Amazon EC2 redhat instance without using keypair?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I have an app I'd like to use that requires an SSH connection to the server.  Unfortunately there are no settings to use my keypair - only un/pw authentication.  Does anyone know a workaround?

I've already tried editing ssh_config, setting PasswordAuthentication yes and reloading.

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 1):

Editing ssh_config and enabling PasswordAuthentication has always worked for me on my instances.  If you application doesn't need to authenticate as root, be sure to create a new user for it.  Also, make sure that you have properly set the password on the instance.  Most public instances scramble the root password at initial launch time (if they are badly configured, possibly at each boot), so you'll definitely need to set it before you can use it.

If that doesn't work, definitely check out the [EC2 forums](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/forum.jspa?forumID=30) for some more specialized help.