# Allowing users to ssh to an EC2 Ubuntu instance?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2

The default way to access an new EC2 instance is by using your key-pair.

How can I allow other users to connect to my instance, without giving them my keys?
(Ideally, I'd like them to be prompted for user/password on login)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523615/how-to-ssh-to-amazon-ec2-redhat-instance-without-using-keypair

Comment: you can also add other keys to your user. so thta you dont need to share your key, but add their key to accept as login

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config and set `PasswordAuthentication` to `yes`.

Enter the command `sudo /etc/init.d/sshd reload`.

Then you could Create a User with:

```
useradd USERNAME
```

(check the man for options on how to set home directory etc...)

Then

```
passwd USERNAME
```

You will be prompted for a New password

Comment: After doing this I try to log in via an FTP client and get "Error: Received unexpected end-of-file from SFTP server.
Error: Could not connect to server"

Answer (score 11):

To save some Ubuntu neophytes like myself some time, newer Ubuntu instances no longer use sshd reload. Instead it is asking for:

```
sudo restart ssh
```

Please see this SO link for more details: https://superuser.com/questions/214799/no-etc-init-d-sshd-file-ubuntu-ec2

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config 
:s/PasswordAuthentication no/PasswordAuthentication yes/   
:wq

sudo /etc/init.d/sshd reload

sudo useradd newuser
```

it prompts you and you enter password.

you wish to change a passwd?

```
sudo passwd newuser
```

Now your users can login with

```
ssh new_user@aws.blah.your_public_ip
```

Comment: PasswordAuthentication no is usually commented out

Comment: In case `sudo /etc/init.d/sshd reload` doesn't work, try sudo `/etc/init.d/ssh reload`. I had to use `ssh` instead of `sshd` on Ubuntu 16.04.